# If $A$ is a real $6 \times 6$ matrix such that $m_A(x)=x^5+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

How do I construct a $6 \times 6$ matrix whose minimal polynomial is $x^5+1$?

I thought of using the companion matrix but it is not possible as coefficient of $x^6$ is $0$.

This is a question from a university entrance exam. I would have attached my attempt but I have made no progress with the problem.

Comment: make a block diagonal matrix, with one block being a $5\times 5$ Companion matrix

Comment: One block is the companion matrix what would be the other block?

Comment: I think @badinmaths understood my hint as that is precisely what they typed up for you.   Forum quality standards really require you to put in more effort here.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow your idea and take

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\omega & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &0  &0  &-1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  0&0 \\ 
0 & 0 &0  & 0 & 1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\omega^5 + 1 = 0$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit. What is the intuition

Answer (score 0):

With $\omega=\exp\big( i\frac{\pi}5 \big)$ we have $X^5+1=(X-\omega)(X-\omega^3)(X+1)(X-\omega^7)(X-\omega^9)$.

Maybe $A=\begin{pmatrix}
\omega&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&\omega^3&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&\omega^7&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&\omega^9
\end{pmatrix}$?